# preg_replace() /e modifier is deprecated for HHVM

Tags: php, regex, symfony-1.4, hhvm

I'm getting error with Symfony 1.4 `Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in /vagrant/lib/util/sfToolkit.class.php on line 365`

The function concerned is below:

```
public static function pregtr($search, $replacePairs)
  {
    if(strpos(implode(', ', $replacePairs),'e') > 0)
      print_r($replacePairs);

    return preg_replace(array_keys($replacePairs),array_values($replacePairs), $search);
  }
```

The values concerned is:

```
Array
(
    [#/(.?)#e] => '::'.strtoupper('\1')
    [/(^|_|-)+(.)/e] => strtoupper('\2')
)
```

How can I change this to what is equivalent using `preg_replace_callback`?

Comment: [Here's the reason it's deprecated, for those interested](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.eval)

Comment: You should upgrade symfony to a version that doesn't use this code/  It's extremely dangerous.

Comment: Eval is evil. /e is just the same as eval... (are you sure you want this? eval can be a security problem!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use the sf 1.5. version maintained by guys from L'Express: https://github.com/LExpress/symfony1 (they have fixed the problem)

If their changes are too much you can check how they managed to solve the 'e modifier' problem and copy their solution. Searching the code for use of `pregtr` it looks that there are only three places where the `e` modifier is used (in `lib/util/sfInflector.class.php` and in filter form classes in the `Doctrine` and `Proper` plugins). It's not that difficult to fix the code by yourself in those places.